# Wordpress theme spam links inside posts

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm creating my own theme in Wordpress. Suddenly in my posts i got random links leading to viagra companies.. can't earse them. I already:

- Checked on plenty malware website scanners - all clear
- Turned off all plugins - links still appear
- ***Changed theme - links disappear***

Moreover i had my own excerpt in functions.php. When i clear it and make default excerpt links disappear but also mine links. When i tried various ways of changing excerpt to display links (for ex. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt) i always get spam links back.

I'm out of ideas. I also searched my files for some "unwanted" code but haven't found anything.
Something is wrong with my theme for sure but i cannot find what.

Will be grateful for any help.
Link to my website: www.weterynariagalecki.pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to Drupal sites a lot, I presume the same holds true for Wordpress.

Have a look at the root file system where your files are hosted. You'll probably see a file in there with `000` file permissions. Pretty good chance it'll be called something like page*nn*-sql.php or something like similar to that. Could also be that `index.php` got replaced (again, check permissions).

[Here is an exerpt from the Drupal.org page on how to deal with this type of hack.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2365547) Again, I know it applies to Drupal, but I believe your problem is the same:

> **Where do attackers exploit Drupal systems?**
>
> index.php, or really any code file A common hack is simply to modify
>   the index.php or any code file in the site such as a template file.
>   The methods are various:
>
> A virus on the computer used to administer the site which uses stored
>   credentials in a FTP tool to edit and upload the files (seriously).
>   Arbitrary code execution on the server and loose server file
>   permissions used to edit or overwrite a file. Arbitrary file upload
>   which was used to upload a command shell which was then used to modify
>   the code. Compare all code files to known good copies, either in the
>   revision control system or from drupal.org (the hacked! module can
>   help with that.)
>
> Look for files on the server that are NOT part of your known Drupal
>   codebase, e.g. modules/system/qseboj.php
>
> Review the files in the "files" directory to ensure they are all
>   appropriate.
>
> It may be helpful to review the combined metadata of owner, group,
>   permissions and timestamps as a fingerprint of the files on the
>   server. If most of the files have one fingerprint and a single other
>   file has a different fingerprint (e.g. edited about when the attack
>   started) that can help you understand what happened.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for late answer - was away for a few days. I followed what you have written and checked all my files and i came across one wierd file "3oQBE38.php", inside wp-admin/network. When i try to download it or even check whats inside (i use FileZilla) my antivirus says it's trojan and blocks opening. Is it possible it could be that?

Comment: That's cool. I was away too. Weekend and such... I see that I have the marked answer, was `3oQBE38.php` the problem file? Did it have the 000 permissions etc...?

Comment: Sorry again, busy days. I found 6 suspicious files, i deleted them and everything seems to work just fine. I compared my files with default files of wordpress, thats hwo i found them. The files didnt have 000 permission but it might be my fault since i changed permissions for all the files in that folder before that.

After all your answer lead to the right direction so i marked it. Thanks!